# Add data into database magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, ce-1.9.0.1

I want to add new column into magento database and want to insert new data into newly created column. Basically what exact i want to do is that when new customer register in my webstore. i want to generate a temporary account number when customer click on register button. on the next page this number will be appear written as temporary account number is = ....... for this purpose i think i need to create a new column in database to store the temporary account number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The customer data is based on EAV, this means you'll need to add an attribute to the attribute set instead of a table column.

There are a couple of tutorials on that, check out [this one](http://www.magecorner.com/adding-custom-customer-attributes/) and [this one](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/). It comes down to creating your own module with an install script that has something like this

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'temp_id', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Temporary ID',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'default' => '',
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'source' => NULL,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

config.xml

```
<default>
    ...
    <resources>
        <your_module_identifier>
            <setup>
                <module>Your_ModuleName</module>
                <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </your_module_identifier >
    </resources>
    ...
</default>
```